# Following-sibling of XML attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am writing an xml-to-json converter using xslt. I convert

```
<raw>
    <id>0</id>
    <type>label</type>
    <title>Test</title>
    <uri>...</uri>
</raw>
```

to

```
{ "id" = "0", "type"="label", "title" = "Test", "uri" = "..." }
```

using an `<xsl:for-each>` iterating over the child nodes of tag `<raw>`, and adding commas with `<xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">, </xsl:if>`.

However, if I want to change the above xml to use attributes instead of child nodes:

```
<raw id="0" type="label" title="Test" uri="..." />
```

the `following-sibling::*` test fails and no commas are added. Is there an equivalent of `following-sibling::*` that works for attributes? If not, is it possible to do what I intend here?

Comment: for-each test="child::*"

then use local-name() to copy node name, for naming attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this XPath for both cases:

```
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">
```

Answer (score 2):

The `following-sibling` axis can be an expensive operation (depending on how many attributes we're talking about). Here's a fairly streamlined solution that accomplishes what you're asking for (and does so without `following-sibling` or any other complicated axis).

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>{ </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="raw/@*" />
    <xsl:text> }</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of
      select="concat('&quot;', name(), '&quot; = &quot;', ., '&quot;')" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is run against your provided XML:**

```
<raw id="0" type="label" title="Test" uri="..."/>
```

**...the desired result is produced:**

```
{ "id" = "0", "type"="label", "title" = "Test", "uri" = "..." }
```

Comment: If the context node is an attribute the following-sibling axis will always be empty http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XSLT_2.html#Axes~following-sibling